# PHP: Retrieve image from MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

I am refactoring some old code, including rewriting basic mysql queries to use PDO.

The following works brilliantly in all browsers and for all image types:

```
$query = 'SELECT image FROM image WHERE imageid=' . $image_id;
$result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn); querycheck($result);
header("Content-type: image");
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Unfortunately, however I rewrite it using PDO, it doesn't work. I've been through the entire PDO documentation and the standard web search, but none of the advice/solutions work.

How can one easily fetch and image from MySQL using PDO and display it?

Edit 1:

Matthew Ratzloff gives what should be the obvious answer below, but it does not work.
Here is the actual code that I test using PDO (and I have tried many variants/parameters):

```
$connectstring_temp = 'mysql:host=' . $A . ';dbname=' .$B;
$dbh_temp = new PDO($connectstring_temp, $login, $password);
#$dbh_temp->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
#$dbh_temp->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);

$sql = "SELECT image FROM image WHERE imageid=" . $image_id;
$query = $dbh_temp->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$query->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-Type: image");
echo $image;
```

I've kept the same syntax, although for the final code $image_id needs to be passed as a parameter. The code above does NOT work. PDO works fine for all other queries of all types.

Comment: Your rewritten-for-PDO code would probably be more helpful.

Comment: I posted the answer which I tested it works then u will just modify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to paramaterize the imageid value and bind the parameter to `PDO::PARAM_LOB`:

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM image WHERE imageid=:id";
$query = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $image_id));

$query->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-Type: image");
echo $image;
```

Of course, you'll also want to specify the complete, correct content type (e.g., image/png).

Comment: While this should work, you do not *need* to use LOB mode for MySQL.  It can be necessary with other databases.

Comment: Never hurts to be explicit.  :-)

Comment: This works now. I can only assume it was a problem with earlier verions of PHP/PDO. Wish I could upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get image from database using PDO:

```
public function getImage($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ?";
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

    $sth->bindParam(1,$id);
    $sth->execute();


    $num = $sth->rowCount();
    if( $num ){
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("Content-type: ".$row['type']);
        print $row['image'];
        exit;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

`type - data type(column name)` such as image/png or image/gif
`image - image data(column name)` stored in table as LOB
`$this->dbh` connection handler
It works for me but now I need to find out how to use it with JS because result of this function is passed to JavaScript code - so called ajax

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach to Image Blobs is using a php file to serve the image, in combination with a GET argument... It's 100% effective and it doesn't involve file creation... For instance, the file to serve the image from the blob would be:

image.php:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anything; charset=utf8', 'account','password');
if (isset($_GET['imageid'])) {
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM image where imageid = ?");
    if ($result->execute(array($_GET['imageid']))) {
        $row=$result->fetch();
        echo $row['pic']; //this prints the image data, transforming the image.php to an image
        }
    } // you can put an "else" here to do something on error...
?>
```

This can be called from you main script... For instance:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anything; charset=utf8', 'account','password');
//... some code to do your job, where you get your imageid from
$imageid=...
?>
<img src="./image.php?imageid=<?php echo $imageid;?>">
```

Answer (score -2):

This code displays all the images in the dabase so you can change it and make it do what you want it to do

getMessage();
    }
    ?>

```
<?php 
#the folder where the images are saved 
$target = "image_uploads/";
$image_name = (isset($_POST['image_name']));

$query = ("SELECT user_id ,image_name FROM tish_images");
$image_show= $con-> prepare($query);
$image_show->execute();
while($record =$image_show->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
#this is the Tannery  operator to replace a pic when an id do not have one
$photo = ($record['image_name']== null)? "me.png":$record['image_name'];
#display image 
echo '<img src="'.$target.$photo.'">';
echo $record['user_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: ...not to mention it doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: Not relevant to the question.