# how mssql image data type works with php pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, image, pdo

I have an MSSQL database with a table which contains data of images (image data type). (Uploaded and successfully used by another non-php-base program.) I would like to show/print these image through my php script.

Based on the answer of [PHP: Retrieve image from MySQL using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999466/php-retrieve-image-from-mysql-using-pdo) . The query works well, but it doesn't show the image only the "no-image" icon.

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM image WHERE imageid=:id";
$query = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $image_id));

$query->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Without the 7th line (header();) It shows something like this:

```
424df630030000000000360000002800000008010000c60000000100200000000000c0300300000000000000000000000000000000004c5d7e004b637f004f6081004d6180004d62820050...
```

In my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express it look like this:
[image: image data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express]

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add this in your data return:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg;");
```

Comment: But if I use this line, as in the 7th line of my example code, it shows only the "image not found" icon. :(

Comment: and, just an addenda here, if you can avoid storing images in a database, please do so. It's better to store an image storage path and retrieve the path instead of attempting to retrieve image data from the database itself. There are normalization and data coherence problems that come with storing image data in a database that can be avoided. For these, and other reasons, it's considered quite bad form to store image data inside a database - even though MSSQL allows for it.

Comment: There may be something going on in your PDO abstraction. Have you tried using PHP's native MSSQL interface to see if it works without PDO?

Comment: - If I have the possibility I don't store images in a database. But in this situation I must retrieve these image from this database made by another program. :(
- With native mssql_query I hade more and more issues. With this PDO I could make a good work but these images.