# Image not displaying using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was using mysqli to retrieve a blob image from MySQL, but I've been moving everything over to PDO. As far as I can tell, this should be working. I've searched and searched the forums for the answer, but I can't see why this doesn't work.

```
// Connection
include 'pdo_db.php';

// Get Image Id for DB Query
$recipe = $_GET['recipe'];

// Execute Query<br>
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myrecipes WHERE Id = ?");
$query->execute(array(
    "Id" => $recipe
));

// Display Image
$query->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image;
```

Comment: have you set PHP to output PDO or SQL errors?

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Answer (score -1):

I make two assumptions: 1) your id is numeric integer, and 2) you'd only need to retrieve 1 row at a time (1 per id).

```
$recipe = (int)$_GET['recipe'];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myrecipes WHERE Id = ? LIMIT 1");
$query->execute(array($recipe));
```

You are referencing the array in `execute` as an `[id]`=>`$recipe` but this is not needed. You only need as a minimum a numeric reference with is handled automatically.

You should not do `SELECT *` but instead specify only the column you want, rather than multiple table-columns.

Comment: Correct on your assumption. It's to pull that one image from that one row, with that recipe ID. I've updated the script with your suggestion, and still at the same place where it's not displaying the image? I'm using the core code from this example in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999466/php-retrieve-image-from-mysql-using-pdo?rq=1

Comment: instead of `SELECT *` you should specify the column name, for the data.

Comment: Thanks. Rookie mistake :/ +1 from a newbie.

Comment: @Pez glad you found it `:-)`